Could not deploy subgraph on graph-node: store error: relation "<contract_event>" already exists
I'm trying to deploy my subgraph on bsc chapel network. I selected the Chapel network, generated code and build the subgraph. Everything worked smoothly.
When I hit the command graph deploy --studio <my-subgraph-slug>, it reverts with the following error:
✖ Failed to deploy to Graph node https://api.studio.thegraph.com/deploy/: Could not deploy subgraph on graph-node: subgraph deployment error: store error: relation "exchanger_with_fee_rec_alternatives_light_chain_owner_nominated" already exists. Deployment: <my-deployment-id>
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION: Error: EEXIT: 1

I tried changing the name of the entity for the ExchangerWithFeeRecAlternatives contract from:
ExchangerWithFeeRecAlternativesLightChainOwnerNominated to ExchangerWithFeeRecAlternativesLightChainOwnerNominatedd,
adding an extra 'd' at the end in subgraph.yaml and schema.graphql files but to no avail.
Please guide me as to what's wrong and how to fix.
